# Auction Algorithm for Euclidean Monopartite Matching Problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, algorithmic-game-theory

Consider an undirected graph on $n$ Euclidean points distributed uniformly at random in the unit square.

A **monopartite Euclidean [matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory))** is an independent edge set of this graph. A *perfect* monopartite Euclidean matching is one where the matching contains all $n$ distinct vertices.

Sometimes **[Auction algorithms](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/3265/P-2108-26912652.pdf;sequence=1) are used to find a matching** of minimal Euclidean length (the sum of Euclidean edge lengths is minimal over all possible matchings). But this only works for bipartite graphs.

**If any vertex may be paired with any other**, such as in a *monopartite* matching, where a set is matched with itself, **can an Auction algorithm still be used?**

I had thought you would have to start an auction at some point, and let it spread like a branching process throughout the graph, with conflicts resolved somehow. But is there a known technique?

This is an example matching in the bipartite case:
[image: A bipartite matching between the white set and the blue set.]

Comment: Note the graph does not have to be random, just monopartite.